# Typescript: Generate types from an object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I just started learning Typescript and need some help with this example.

```js
const alphabet = {
    'a': {lower: 97, upper: 65},
    'b': {lower: 98, upper: 66}
}

type Char = 'a' | 'b'

function printSome(char: Char){
    console.log(alphabet[char])
}
```

Instead of manually updating the `Char` type, I'd like to dynamically update generate types from the `alphabet` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [keyof](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html) and [typeof](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) operators:

```
const alphabet = {
    'a': {lower: 97, upper: 65},
    'b': {lower: 98, upper: 66}
}

type Char = keyof typeof alphabet;

function printSome(char: Char){
    console.log(alphabet[char])
}
```

This basically turns `alphabet` into a type and then gets the keys of that type.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I tried that and it doesn't work for me for some reason. I'm getting this error: 'alphabet' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof alphabet'? ts(2749)

Comment: @AnonymousAnonymous Oops, updated.

Comment: Nice! It worked. Thanks again. BTW, for some reason why I add an interface or type definition for the `alphabet ` object, it stops working. Any ideas why is that?

Comment: @AnonymousAnonymous I would need to see what you're trying to do. If you post another SO question, add a link and I'll take a look.

Comment: i compiled the second part for my question and posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71136635/typescript-generate-types-from-an-object-with-the-interface. If you have a chance, please take a took.