# Typescript: Generate types from an object with the interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

It's the second part for [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/125748064?noredirect=1) that was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/125748064?noredirect=1). I've been helped with the solution for my previous problem, but once I added the interface for the `alphabet` object, Typescript stopped detecting that I provided the incorrect value.

```js
interface ICharMap {
    lower: number
    upper: number
}

const alphabet: {[key: string]: ICharMap} = {
    'a': {lower: 97, upper: 65},
    'b': {lower: 98, upper: 66}
}

type Char = keyof typeof alphabet;

function printSome(char: Char){
    console.log(char)
}

printSome('c') \\ Typescript does not detect that the incorrect value is passed.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
interface ICharMap {
  lower: number
  upper: number
}

type Letter = 'a' | 'b'

const alphabet: Record<Letter, ICharMap> = {
  'a': {lower: 97, upper: 65},
  'b': {lower: 98, upper: 66}
}

function printSome(char: Letter){
  console.log(char);
  console.log(alphabet[char]); // no error; TS knows that char is in alphabet
}

printSome('c') // error
```

Comment: If this works, I'd wait to mark it as the answer. Someone else might post a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

It is because your alphabet has `{[key: string]}` so when you do `keyof typeof alphabet`
it returns string, with that you are allowed to pass any string.

If you modify your script like this then it will tell typescript that you should pass only 'a' and 'b'

```
interface ICharMap {
    lower: number
    upper: number
}

type keys = 'a' | 'b';

const alphabet: {[key in keys]: ICharMap} = {
    'a': {lower: 97, upper: 65},
    'b': {lower: 98, upper: 66}
}

type Char = keyof typeof alphabet;

function printSome(char: Char){
    console.log(char)
}
printSome('c')
```